# How did 秘 "bi" become "mi"?

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation

I came across this comment just now:

> “秘”声符是“必”没问题，但是并不是说“秘”和“必”一定同音，“秘”这个字是北京话读错了，其实应该读bi，“秘鲁”一词还残存bi的读音

Which got me thinking.

---

秘 is still read "bi" in:

- surnames
- transcriptions (e.g.: Peru)

---

[Cantonese](http://cccanto.org/search.php?q=%E7%A7%98) carries the pronunciation:

> bei3

---

[Sichuanese](https://www.tiaodengyedu.com/html/348/348599/111232651.html) also has 秘 as "bei" in certain instances:

> 秘密 beimi 秘，读“背”。成都人通常称有所隐蔽，不让人知道的话及事情：～档案│～活动。又为“背密”。

---

[Matthews'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathews%27_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary) also has it listed under "bi":

> [image]

---

[Middle Chinese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A7%98) pronunciations also seem to be way close to "bi" than "mi."

So what gives? Where did "mi" come from?

edit: I'm thinking maybe 秘 sounded like 屄, and it was changed purposely because of taboos. (http://www.sohu.com/a/219931086_413427) "山东方言对女性的某个器官的发音为“比”，因此，为了避免与比字同音，凡是在读笔字时都要读成北，于是，便有了钢北，毛北，圆柱北。"

Comment: I think someone confused 秘密(bi mi)  with 密密(mi mi). the former means "secret " the latter means "secretly";  and for some reason people start reading 秘 as mi too. As the reference stated, it was Beijing dialect read it wrong. Cantonese doesn't have this problem

Comment: The problem with 秘 sounded like 屄 can be fixed by a tone change, no need to change the pinyin itself

Comment: @TangHo The tones are different to begin with, but sometimes these types of evolution do take place.

Comment: Language evolves over time, and usually in a gradual way. Consider that the lip-placement of "m" and "b" is actually the same, lips pressed together in front. It's not hard to imagine how these pronunciations can diverge over time.

Comment: yes, b and m are both labial consonants.

Comment: You see there's a similar unanswered question here: http://c.tieba.baidu.com/p/6226368666

Comment: The right form of **secret** is **祕密**, I think that due to the radical **礻** was written to **示** at first (without the bottom hook in the middle vertical stoke), it is so similar to **禾**, so some ordinary people wrote **祕** as **秘** by mistake, and also read **秘密** as **祕密** by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but both「秘」and「泌」underwent the same kinds of shifts (b > m) in certain topolects, so I would just treat it as a simple phonological shift within the labial consonant group (rather than something more "exciting"). I do not believe that the comments on it being a "Mandarin thing" are correct.

[image]

> Although "time" seems like a cop-out, I would point to similar shifts over "time" like
>
> [image]